# Type wrongly interpreted when overloading in Typescript

Tags: typescript, overloading

Consider the following class and a `factory` method with two implementations

```
class SomeClass {
  public someId: number;
  public someProp: string;
  constructor(input) {
    // do some internal stuff with input;
  }
}
function factory(singleInput: {}): SomeClass;
function factory(multipleInput: Array<{}>): Array<SomeClass>;
function factory(singleOrMultipleInput: {} | Array<{}>): SomeClass | Array<SomeClass> {
  if (singleOrMultipleInput instanceof Array) {
    // case multiple input: Array<{}>
    const arrayOfSomeClass = singleOrMultipleInput.map(ro => new SomeClass(singleOrMultipleInput)); // indeed is shown as SomeClass[]
    return arrayOfSomeClass;
  } else {
    // case single input: {}
    const singleSomeClass = new SomeClass(singleOrMultipleInput); // indeed is shown as SomeClass
    return singleSomeClass;
  }
}
```

In words: when calling `factory` with a `{}` as parameter (a plain object), I want it to return an instance of `SomeClass`. When calling `factory` with an array of objects, `[{}, {}, {}]`, I want it to return a array of instances of `SomeClass`, like `[SomeClass, SomeClass, SomeClass]`.

The snippet below shows that the TypeScript interpreted doesn't recognise it as such.

```
const singleInput: {} = {};
const multipleInput: Array<{}> = [{}, {}, {}];
let singleResult = factory({}); // is SomeClass, as expected
const multipleResult = factory([{}]); // no longer is SomeClass[] ?!
singleResult.someId = 123;
multipleResult.someId = 456; // the interpreter should flag this as wrong
singleResult = multipleResult; // also shouldn't be possible without an warning from the interpreter
```

However, within the factory method, `arrayOfSomeClass` and `singleSomeClass` are typed correctly. Why does `multipleResult` not show as `SomeClass[]` by the interpreter?

Follow up question: how can it be implemented such that the interpreter shows the types as I would expected? (preferably having the factory method as a `static`  (generic?) method of `SomeClass` (I realise this can probably be achieved by avoiding overloading, but thats not what I'm looking for)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure, but seems instanceof checks must be done in same order as overloads.

```
function factory(multipleInput: Array<{}>): Array<SomeClass>;
function factory(singleInput: {}): SomeClass;
function factory(singleOrMultipleInput: {} | Array<{}>): SomeClass | Array<SomeClass>
```

It is working as expected.

EDIT: compiler is taking first overload and is trying to validate it.

So it can pass to else { } block using array of objects, without erros, 
as for compiler Array is a case of {}.

ONE MORE UPDATE:

From this perspective it seems to be a bug.

```
function acceptsObjectType(obj:{}) {
  return obj;
}

let a = [];
a = acceptsObjectType(a);
```

But this is ok.

```
function acceptsObjectType(obj:{}) {
  return obj;
}

let a:{} = [];
a = acceptsObjectType(a);
```

Comment: Jeez... you're right. That seems like a TypeScript bug. Going to wait for a little longer to see if someone can come up with a proper explanation as to *why*, if not I'll mark your answer as correct.

Comment: I don't see a TypeScript bug anywhere... what's the issue?

Comment: In typescript 2.9 I'm getting an error "Type {} is not assignable to type any[]", but type any[] is assignable to {}. So it is not a bug.

Comment: I feel that it shouldn't matter in what order you declare the overloads (your solution compared to my initial example). Might not be a *bug*, but (at least to me) it is definitely unexpected behaviour; afaik it wouldn't behave like this in e.g. C#. Thanks for the input y'all!

Comment: From the [TypeScript handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads):  "[The compiler] looks at the overload list, and proceeding with the first overload attempts to call the function with the provided parameters. If it finds a match, it picks this overload as the correct overload. For this reason, its customary to order overloads from most specific to least specific."